# Tensorflow Network Test Accuracy Fails to Improve on CIFAR 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I'm new to Tensorflow. Right now, I'm trying to create a simple 4 layer fully connected neural network to classify the CIFAR-10 dataset. However, on my testset, the neural network accuracy on the test set is completely static, and is stuck at 11%.

I know that a fully connected neural network is probably not ideal fo this task, but it is weird that the network is not improving/changing at all. So I was wondering if anyone knows the solution to my problem. I have copied my code below, any help is appreciated! Thank you very much.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

y_train_one_hot = np.zeros((y_train.shape[0], 10))
for i in range(y_train.shape[0]):
    y_train_one_hot[i][y_train[i]] = 1

y_test_one_hot = np.zeros((y_test.shape[0], 10))
for i in range(y_test.shape[0]):
    y_test_one_hot[i][y_test[i]] = 1


x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), name='X')
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 10), name='Y')
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

x_flatten = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 32*32*3])
nn = tf.layers.dense(x_flatten, 1028, activation=tf.nn.relu)
nn = tf.nn.dropout(nn, keep_prob)
nn = tf.layers.dense(nn, 1028, activation=tf.nn.relu)
nn = tf.nn.dropout(nn, keep_prob)
nn = tf.layers.dense(nn, 512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
nn = tf.nn.dropout(nn, keep_prob)
prediction = tf.layers.dense(nn, 10, activation=tf.nn.relu)

cross_entropy = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=y, logits=prediction)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for iteration in range(1000):
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: x_train[:1000], y: y_train_one_hot[:1000], keep_prob: 0.5})
        if iteration % 10 == 0:
            acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test[:100], y: y_test_one_hot[:100], keep_prob: 1.0})
            print(acc)
```

Comment: You are applying softmax two times, once in your last layer, and again in the softmax_cross_entropy

Comment: Hi Matias, thanks for your reply! Noted, but after I changed the prediction layer activation to relu, my test accuracy still remains at 10%....

Comment: Try having your `AdamOptimizer` minimize `cross_entropy` instead of `loss`. Also, I found in my code, I do 500000 passes instead of 1000. [Here's how I approach it](https://gist.github.com/samclane/316d6430a89fb990a541c283d511eef1)

Comment: @watersnake Got it thanks! Just wondering what was your accuracy on the test set?

Comment: I was getting something like 70-75%. The book says I should be getting ~83%, but I don't. There might be a bug in my code, as 75% is the norm with 2 convolutional layers, but adding a 3rd should have increased it. I'm pretty new at this as well. EDIT: It wasn't just a 3rd layer, but some more model complexity. 75% should be good.